# How to comapre all records of two collections in mongodb using mapreduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have an use case in which I want to compare each record of two collections in mongodb and after comparing each record I need to find mismatch fields of all record.

Let us take an example, in collection1 I have one record as {id : 1, name : "bks"}
and in collection2 I have a record as {id : 1, name : "abc"}
When I compare above two records with same key, then field name is a mismatch field as name is different.

I am thinking to achieve this use case using mapreduce in mongodb. But I am facing some problems while accessing collection name in map function. When I tried to compare it in map function, I got error as : **"errmsg" : "exception: ReferenceError: db is not defined near '**

Can anyone give me some thoughts on how to compare records using mapreduce?

Answer (score 0):

I might have helped you to [read the documentation:](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/)

> When upgrading to MongoDB 2.4, you will need to refactor your code if your map-reduce operations, group commands, or $where operator expressions include any global shell functions or properties that are no longer available, such as **db**.

So from your error fragment, you appear to be referencing `db` in order to access another collection. You cannot do that.

If indeed you are intending to "compare" items in one collection to those in another, then there is no other approach other than looping code:

```js
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {

    var another = db.anothercollection.findOne({ "_id": doc._id });

    // Code to compare

})
```

There is simply no concept of "joins" as such available to MongoDB, and operations such as `mapReduce` or `aggregate` or others strictly work with **one** collection only.

The exception is [**`db.eval()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/), but as per all of **strict warnings** in the documentation, this is almost always a very bad idea.

Live with your comparison in looping code.

Comment: @Nell : Thanks for you reply. But I have 20-30 millions of records in both collections then does it take more time?

Comment: @bks. But what? But you are expecting someone to say "this is how you do it?". You cannot do this with mapReduce as per the documentation link. There is `db.eval()` but it is not a really good option unless you are doing this one off. And plain not applicable if your collection is sharded.